# MariaDB with ColumnStore spawns a lot of child processes

Tags: mariadb, columnstore

I'm having a strange issue with a MariaDB Community 10.6 with ColumnStore installation running on a Ubuntu 20.04.

After I start the server and my application begins sending queries to it, the process ExeMgr seems to spawn an infinity number of child processes. It keeps growing and growing and all of them has a TCP connection with the MariaDb process, which is kind of expected, since MariaDB redirects the query to the ColumnStore engine. It's worth mentioning that there are SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE instructions going into the ColumnStore engine.

This is the output of the netstat command:

```
. . .
# netstat -anp | grep ExeMgr
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8601            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      89497/ExeMgr        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8601          127.0.0.1:10090         ESTABLISHED 89497/ExeMgr        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8601          127.0.0.1:62000         ESTABLISHED 89497/ExeMgr        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8601          127.0.0.1:11230         ESTABLISHED 89497/ExeMgr        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8601          127.0.0.1:61200         ESTABLISHED 89497/ExeMgr        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8601          127.0.0.1:60304         ESTABLISHED 89497/ExeMgr        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8601          127.0.0.1:60892         ESTABLISHED 89497/ExeMgr        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8601          127.0.0.1:61992         ESTABLISHED 89497/ExeMgr        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8601          127.0.0.1:61038         ESTABLISHED 89497/ExeMgr        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8601          127.0.0.1:61410         ESTABLISHED 89497/ExeMgr        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8601          127.0.0.1:11680         ESTABLISHED 89497/ExeMgr        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8601          127.0.0.1:60838         ESTABLISHED 89497/ExeMgr        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8601          127.0.0.1:61226         ESTABLISHED 89497/ExeMgr        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8601          127.0.0.1:60474         ESTABLISHED 89497/ExeMgr        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8601          127.0.0.1:12740         ESTABLISHED 89497/ExeMgr        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8601          127.0.0.1:10986         ESTABLISHED 89497/ExeMgr        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8601          127.0.0.1:10886         ESTABLISHED 89497/ExeMgr        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8601          127.0.0.1:61332         ESTABLISHED 89497/ExeMgr        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8601          127.0.0.1:10068         ESTABLISHED 89497/ExeMgr
. . .
```

And this is the output of the command `pstree`. At the moment when I took it, there were already 480 ExeMgr subprocesses running:

[image: pstree output]

My application is a NodeJS application and it does have a connection pool. But we are working with a max number of 5 connections. When I run the commando `show processlist` I can see only 5 connections as expected.

Has anyone faced this problem? Maybe it is some kind of bug or a configuration that I missed appyling on the server?

Thanks for any help!